How to Convert a Virtual Machine Image to a Physical Machine?
I have a virtual machine running on Virt-Manager, and I need to convert this virtual machine into a physical machine. The virtual machine is running SONiC.
Could someone provide a detailed guide or point me to resources on how to achieve this? Specifically, I am looking for:
Steps to prepare the virtual machine for conversion.
Tools required for the conversion process.
Detailed instructions on transferring the virtual machine image to a physical disk.
Any potential pitfalls or common issues to watch out for during the process.
Thank you in advance for your help!
Edit:
I used qemu-img to convert the .qcow2 file to .raw and it was transformed and decompressed.
Then I used dd to put this .raw in /dev/sdX and it worked perfectly.
Thank you all, especially @eyoung100.

Does this help? Migrate from a virtual machine (VM) to a physical system.  The trick here is the RAW image format.

Also: CloneZilla - Restore Disk Image.  If you still need step-by-step instructions let me kno as the answer will take an hour or so.  I'm very thorough.

I tried taking the .qcow2 file from the vm and converting it to .raw format (qemu-img) and using DD to write it into my /dev/sdX. But it's not working.

I don't have much experience using clonezilla.  @eyoung100

Did the image conversion succeed?  .QCow2 to ..img  i.e. Are you just having issues with DD? See here.  Note that you can't be using the drive you're copying to.

@eyoung100 The previous problem when using DD was that the conversion of the .qcow2 file to .raw had become corrupted. I was trying to use dd with this corrupt .raw file without realizing it, so I was unable to clone it on the device.
